# Smear/blur text/image in a screen shot

Tags: osx, image-editing

I often seen screen shots with areas of sensitive information smeared/blurred to make it unintelligible.

How can I do that image-smearing simply and inexpensively as a Mac user?

The words "simply" and "inexpensively" mean *not* Photoshop, GIMP, or similar high-end graphics manipulation apps. Normally I just use [Preview.app](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preview_%28Mac_OS%29), and sometimes [Grab.app](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grab_%28software%29) or [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/omnigraffle) for my screen shots. I'm looking for something MacPaint-simple.

Comment: Can't you hide text with OmniGraffle?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt In OmniGraffle I can draw an opaque box over a sensitive area, or a white box on a white background to block the view. But there is no smearing or blurring tool. OmniGraffle is a drawing/vector app, no paint/bitmap editing.

Comment: oh OK I wasn't sure whether drawing an opaque box counted as smearing. I would be wary regarding non-opaque solutions as it's tough to be sure it cannot be unblurred, e.g. http://www.nbcnews.com/id/21190969/ns/world_news-europe/t/interpol-unscrambles-photo-id-pedophile/

Comment: Valid point about security, but we are not talking Top Secret data in my cases. A side-benefit: blurring helps avoid distraction with the user so they focus on the important parts while still keeping a somewhat natural look of the screen.

Comment: Yep sure I understand the use, just making sure you (and future readers) know the potential risks :)

Answer (score 11):

You can do this for free with [**Skitch**](http://evernote.com/skitch/).

[image]

Comment: Bonus points for animated demo. Next I'll have to ask what software I can use to simply make an animated demo. :-)

Comment: @BasilBourque See [Make a GIF video](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7019/make-a-gif-video)