# Add new frame, delete existing frame and rearrange frame an animated GIF file

Tags: images, offline, gif

Is there a windows application that can add a new frame, delete existing frame(s) and rearrange existing frames from an animated GIF file?

The application needs to:

- Freeware or Open source (no watermark after add or delete or rearrange frames)
- Portable ('good to have')
- Offline (do not require Internet in order to function)
- Support big animated GIF file (should not freeze or crash when opening a Animated GIF file of minimum size of 1 MB to a max size of 500 MB given that the hardware free RAM is more than 2GB and a i3 CPU is used.)

I tried [GifCam](http://blog.bahraniapps.com/gifcam/) but it can only allow delete. It does not allow to add a new frame at any position or rearrange existing frames.

I also tried [PhotoScape](http://www.photoscape.org/ps/main/index.php) but it crash when opening a animated GIF of 1 MB.

Comment: Have you tried [ScreenToGif](https://screentogif.codeplex.com/)? It is at least able to rearrange and delete frames from an animated gif. I have not tried to open a big gif though.