# Free screen recorder to animated GIF on Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, screen-recording, gif

I'm looking for a free screen recorder to short animated GIFs for Windows. It needs to support:

- recording part of the screen
- displaying mouse clicks as dots
- edits (cuting, merging and reorganising)
- adding subtitles or other elements

Comment: There are plenty of screen capture (video) programs and there are plenty of video-to-gif converters. I think you find more solutions doing it in two steps.

Comment: Some answers here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7019/screen-recording-gif-video-tool-for-mac-os-x You can always check the related questions even if they ask for a different OS.